How to parse out text from PDF into pandas dataframe
I am working on scraping data from several infographics on ridership data for Amtrak.  I want to collect the yearly ridership #s and addresses of each station in the US.
Here is my code for one station:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import fitz 

url_abe = 'https://www.railpassengers.org/site/assets/files/1679/abe.pdf'
page = requests.get(url_abe)

# Save the PDF file locally
pdf_path = 'abe.pdf'
with open(pdf_path, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(page.content)
    
# Step 2: Extract text from the PDF file
def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    # Open the PDF file
    document = fitz.open(pdf_path)
    
    # Iterate through each page and extract text
    text = ''
    for page_num in range(len(document)):
        page = document.load_page(page_num)
        text += page.get_text()
    
    return text

# Get the extracted text
pdf_text = extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path)

How can I then parse this out to get a pandas dataframe that looks like the following:
2016   2017   2018   2019   2020   2021   2022   Address
37161  37045  37867  39108  19743  14180  34040  18 E Bel Air Ave Aberdeen, MD 21001-3701


I figured it out:
def extract_all_ridership_numbers(text):
    pattern = re.compile(r'\b\d{2},\d{3}\b')
    
    # Find all matches in the text
    matches = pattern.findall(text)
    
    # Return all matches
    return matches

# Extract all ridership numbers
ridership_numbers = extract_all_ridership_numbers(pdf_text)

# Print the extracted ridership numbers
print('Extracted Ridership Numbers:', ridership_numbers)

df = pd.DataFrame(ridership_numbers, columns=['Ridership Numbers'])[0:7]
df['Year'] = [2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022]


If the test you are extracting is TAB delimited, then you can:
pd.DataFrame([x.split('\t') for x in pdf_text], columns=['2016', '2017'])

You need to complete the list of columns in the example above
